# Do I need to check if a Facebook UserID provided by a client is actually a valid UserID?

Tags: facebook, security, facebook-graph-api, web

For instance, let's say I'm getting a picture for a user. The client code might call `mysite.com/api/getProfilePicture?user=000123` and my app will then send back a URL for the appropriate image to load. Internally, it'd be making an API call to `/v2.6/{user_id}/picture` literally just taking the user parameter it receives and placing it in that string. I think I want to keep this serverside so that the client doesn't have to worry about where the profile picture comes from (if I end up adding, for example, Google+ login in the future).

Is this a security concern? Could a nefarious user make a call to `mysite.com/api/getProfilePicture?user=destructiveEndpoint` and then have it run `/v2.6/destructiveEndpoint/picture`? Or are there no such destructive endpoints to worry about (since the app secret is not being used here). If there *are* destructive endpoints to worry about, I should then be making sure that whatever userid I get is a valid one before using it, correct?

Answer (score 1):

So after SQL injection now comes API parameter injection :)

If you just take any arbitrary string you get and put it somewhere into the Graph API URL, theoretically scenarios are imaginable where that could lead to unwanted results, yes.

But every API endpoint that could create/alter/delete anything needs an access token - in fact, the `/ picture` endpoints are the only ones that don't.

So even if I was able to "inject" something into your API call, the most likely outcome is that the API will simply complain that the operation needs a valid access token.

Maybe I'd even manage to inject an access token, too - but then I could most likely make that very same API call outside of your app, too.

---

For now, Facebook profile IDs contain digits only - so if you want to validate the input, that's what I would check for. (But FB engineers have already stated on multiple occasions, that this might change in the future as well.)

Comment: So basically, someone could manipulate things (that aren't the picture endpoint) to delete/alter content, but it would only be their own so there'd be no point. Correct?

There's no real way to prevent against someone taking the token out of the cookie clientside and making requests themselves, is there? And I suppose it doesn't really matter if they can, at that point, right?

Comment: As long as they only have their own user access token to play with, they will only be able to do stuff that affects them/their own account. / The docs have a chapter that deals with securing API requests, in regard to what people can possibly do with stolen access tokens - by requiring the app-secret proof in app settings you can further lock that down. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/securing-requests